# Why did my computer wake me up?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

Tonight, at 02:36 AM, my bedroom computer (Windows 10 1511) decided to wake up from hibernation.

Obviously, my first instinct was to yell at it for waking me up in the middle of the night (it's not a "silent" PC). Since my wife was still asleep, what I actually did was to shut it down (fully) and worry about it later.

Later is now, and I'd like to find out why, oh why, it decided to do such a thing at such an impossible time.

I've checked the following:

Power settings: "Allow wake timers" is set to "Disabled".

[image: Power Options screenshot]

Event log: The wake source is "unknown".

[image: Event Log screenshot]

How can I find out what caused this madness?

Comment: Look for a Scheduled Task. In a `cmd` shell run `schtasks | findstr -i 02:36`

Comment: @DavidPostill: No result. Anyway, shouldn't "Allow wake timers: Disable" prevent tasks from waking the PC at a given time?

Comment: Not always. Windows 10 has a habit of ignoring that setting. Anyway you should read the dupe question I'm about to link to ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Wow, that's a thorough answer! It's technically not a duplicate (it won't allow me to find out "what caused this exact wake"), but since this solves my problem as well, I won't complain.